# SQL Server : how to create a job that will take a field from a row and push it to another table, every time a row gets added

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

I have two tables, `Orders` and `RetailPrices`.

The `order` table has columns purchase order number, item number(s), and sale price.

Here is the query

```
SELECT TOP 10 O.Control_Number, OD.Item_Number, OD.Price-- ,* 
FROM Orders O
LEFT JOIN Order_Detail OD ON O.Company_Code = OD.Company_Code 
                       AND O.Division_Code = OD.Division_Code 
                       AND O.Control_Number = OD.Control_Number
WHERE O.Customer_Number = 'ECOM2X'
ORDER BY O.DateRecordModified DESC
```

And this is what it returns:

```
Control Item_Number     Price
-------------------------------
205746  910M2286NSZ     45.00
205746  910M2210NSZ     45.00
205746  910M2250NSZ     45.00
205747  910B2307NSZ     60.00
205747  910B2155NSZ     65.00
486737  31A450B101L     58.00
486737  31A450B101L     58.00
205745  910B2201NSZ     70.00
205744  910B2448NSZ     65.00
205743  910B2466NSZ     65.00
```

The retail table has the item number and it's retail price.

What I want to happen is that every time an order gets placed and our order table gets updated, I want a job to run and check every item number in that purchase order.

Then it checks if that item number already exists in the `RetailPrices` table. If it does, do nothing. But if it doesn't I would want to add that item to the table, and record it's sell price as it's retail price.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: This sounds like something that belongs in your app code whenever you save an order.  Barring that, you could try a trigger (but I wouldn't recommend it unless you have to, my experience is that they then to bite you in the rear if you aren't very careful and document very well (and even then...)).

Comment: How are item numbers even being placed on orders if they don't exist in RetailPrices? I believe your processes are backwards. Your system should require an item number in RetailPrices (or better yet, and actual ItemNumbers table) before being allowed on an order.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is a table trigger.  If you google them you'll see they are well documented.  In particular you'd be looking at an insert trigger.  A triggers functionality is basically on `ADD/EDIT/DELETE` on table do `SOMETHING`.

Now the warning.  Without a great amount of care Triggers can be your worst nightmare.  They hide functionality, they can cause blocks or slow downs, they are the last thing that seasoned dba/dbd will expect or look for.

The only time I ever use triggers is for logging - and even then I prefer to write logs into my stored procedures instead, and only use triggers if the front end guys are doing any direct SQL calls.

I would think about the requirement a bit further first and try to decide if this is the best approach.  Does the table need to be updated immediately? Can it be updated overnight or some other schedule.  Can you do the update prior to running a report?  Have a think along those lines first.

Let us know what you decide to do, and if you do decide to use triggers then please be careful, and I'd advise adding a print command to the trigger so if you run it from SSMS or similar there's a reminder that the trigger is in place.  That can really help in the long run.

Comment: I could do it so it is updated overnight. Then I would just create a stored procedure and then create a job out of it?

Comment: That would be a good option for several reasons.  The entire process is more visible. There's no overheads or locks during write processes on the table.  With the best will in the world, incremental changes almost always go out of sync at some point.